# Streamlining Python v3.X code with Requests and HTTP/HTTPS

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have the below code in Python 3.7. In essence, I have a list containing lots of URLs that commence with *http://*. The intention of my code is:-

- Use requests.head() to check if the URL is up
- If it doesn't return a 200 status, replace `http` in the *url* variable with `https`
- Use requests.head() to check if the URL is up now with https
- If it doesn't return a 200 status, continue to the next URL in the list

```
    import requests    
    my_list = [#Lots of URLs in this list]
    for url in my_list:
        r = requests.head(url)
        if r.status_code==200:
            print("website %s is up" % url)
        else:
            print("URL %s is not accessible" % url)
            url = url.replace('http', 'https')
            print("Now trying URL %s" % url)
            r = requests.head(url, headers=headers)
            if r.status_code==200:
                print("website using HTTPS %s is up" % url)
            else:
                print("website %s is still not accessible" % url)
```

My code just doesn't appear very efficient. I am thinking of looking at some sort of function for the requests.head() so that I an now repeating it but I still feel there must be a more efficient way of carrying out the above.

Any suggestions? Does the `requests` module have any option that can be set to check HTTP and HTTPS? I couldn't find anything online

Answer (score 0):

Multithreading

```py
import requests 

def worker(url):
    r = requests.head(url)
    if r.status_code==200:
        print("website %s is up" % url)
    else:
        print("URL %s is not accessible" % url)
        url = url.replace('http', 'https')
        print("Now trying URL %s" % url)
        r = requests.head(url, headers=headers)
        if r.status_code==200:
            print("website using HTTPS %s is up" % url)
        else:
            print("website %s is still not accessible" % url)

from _thread import start_new_thread

for url in list_of_your_url:
    start_new_thread(worker,(url,))
```